# Движение подсветки кнопки за курсором

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Здравствуйте! Я хотел бы стилизовать кнопки для веб-сайта в стиле win7.
При наведении на кнопку должна плавно появятся подсветка и она должна следовать за курсором по кнопке, при убирании курсора с кнопки - подсветка плавно исчезает. В вебе я совсем-совсем новичок, поэтому любые вещи, даже самые простые - для меня очень сложны.

Для решения данной задачи нашёл два подхода:

Двигать градиент.

```js
var originalBG = '',
    lightColor = 'fff',
    gradientSize = 5;

$('div')
.mousemove(function(e) {
    originalBG = $("div").css("background-color");
    x  = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    y  = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
    xy = x + " " + y;

    bgWebKit = "-webkit-gradient(radial, " + xy + ", 0, " + xy + ", 100, from(rgba(255,255,255,0.8)), to(rgba(255,255,255,0.0))), " + originalBG;
    bgMoz    = "-moz-radial-gradient(" + x + "px " + y + "px 45deg, circle, " + lightColor + " 0%, " + originalBG + " " + gradientSize + "px)";

    $(this)
      .css({ background: bgWebKit })
      .css({ background: bgMoz });

}).mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).css({ background: originalBG });
});
```

```css
div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 500px;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Двигать див1 внутри дива2

```js
var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0, limitX = 150-15, limitY = 150-15;
$('.container').mousemove(function(e){
   $("#follower").show();
  var offset = $('.container').offset();
    console.log(e);
   mouseX = Math.min(e.pageX - offset.left, limitX);
   mouseY = Math.min(e.pageY - offset.top, limitY);
   if (mouseX < 0) mouseX = 0;
   if (mouseY < 0) mouseY = 0;
});

$('.container').mouseleave(function() {
        $("#follower").hide(); 
});    

// cache the selector
var follower = $("#follower");
var xp = 0, yp = 0;
var loop = setInterval(function(){
    // change 12 to alter damping higher is slower
    xp += (mouseX - xp) / 12;
    yp += (mouseY - yp) / 12;
    follower.css({left:xp, top:yp});
    
}, 30);
```

```css
#follower{
  position : relative;
  background-color : yellow;
  width:15px;
  height:15px;
  border-radius:50px;
  margin: -10px 0 0 -10px;
    display: none
}

.centerdiv {
    width:150px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    position:relative;
}
.container
{
    width:150px;
    height:150px;   
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    border:1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="centerdiv">
<div class="container">
        <div id="follower"></div>
</div></div>
```

**Какой способ более оптимален?
Может есть какие-то иные способы или готовые реализации?**

Взяв за основу второй способ, породил вот это творение:
https://jsfiddle.net/fsb1337/jqnrfLL4/
Но тут у меня проблема в том, что нужно задавать актуальные координаты для конкретного экземпляра класса .follower в зависимости от того на какой конкретный экземпляр класса .container навели мышь. **Как это сделать?**

Answer (score 4):

```js
ns4 = (document.layers) ? true : false
ie4 = (document.all) ? true : false

function init() {
  if (ns4) {
    document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEMOVE);
  }
  document.onmousemove = mousemove;
}

function mousemove(event) {
  var mouse_x = y = 0;
  if (document.attachEvent != null) {
    mouse_x = window.event.clientX;
    mouse_y = window.event.clientY;
  } else if (!document.attachEvent && document.addEventListener) {
    mouse_x = event.clientX - 150;
    mouse_y = event.clientY - 100;
  }
  document.getElementById('test').style.backgroundPosition = '0 0,0 0,' + mouse_x + 'px ' + mouse_y + 'px,0 0';

}
init()
```

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(transparent, rgba(0, 0, 0, .8) 100%), url('http://s017.radikal.ru/i443/1508/44/6a78a290f954.png'), url('http://s45.radikal.ru/i109/1508/08/0c104c0f72c8.png') no-repeat, #000;
  background-position: 0 0, 0 0, 100px 100px, 0 0;
}
```

```html
<body id="test">
</body>
```